# github composer [InvalidArgumentException] Could not find a matching version of package Tohidda/payping

Tags: laravel, git, github, package, gitlab

i develop package for laravel payment and upload on github
. in this link
https://github.com/tdanandeh/payping

https://packagist.org/packages/tdanandeh/payping

when i use composer for install i see this error

```
 [InvalidArgumentException]                                                                                                                                                            
  Could not find a matching version of package Tohidda/payping. Check the package spelling, your version constraint and that the package is available in a stability which matches you  
  r minimum-stability (dev).
```

Comment: you need to setup https://packagist.org/ then you need to Publishing Packages then you can use

Comment: this repository is not in packagist , therefore you can't install it, try clone it and add it to your project using composer psr-4 then you can use it

Comment: @KamleshPaul thank you brow i uploaded in packagist but i see   [InvalidArgumentException]  https://packagist.org/packages/tdanandeh/payping

Comment: @AmirJani thank you please help me more

Comment: it is `composer require tdanandeh/payping` not `composer require Tohidda/payping` please check

Comment: @TohidDa I didn't know that it's your own package, look at Kamalesh comment, it's a writing problem

Comment: @KamleshPaul thank you it is work fine...i change user name and use old...thanks